# Cache WebView in Xamarin.Forms for iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview, offline

I am creating an app in Xamarin.Forms(C#) that is cross platform. I have a website that is also a pwa(progressive web app). I am trying to access it through a WebView and also allow for offline viewing of the last data cached. I have it working perfectly on Android by enabling:

`webView.Settings.SetAppCacheEnabled(true);`

However I cannot seem to get it to work correctly on iOS. 
I am very new to app development and am trying to learn. Any help in learning would be appreciated.

Simple mock/poc example:

```
        ToolbarItem refresh;
        WebView webView;

        public TestingWebCache() {
            InitializeComponent();
            Title = "Website";
            IconImageSource = "airport.png";
            webView = new WebView();

            refresh = new ToolbarItem {
                IconImageSource = "refresh.png"
            };
            refresh.Clicked += Refresh;
            ToolbarItems.Add(refresh);

            init();

            Content = webView;
        }

        private void init() {
            webView.Source = "https://www.google.com" //not the website im using but used for testing
        }

        private async void Refresh(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            TRCWebViewItem.Reload();
        }
```

I have looked at many resources, including the iOS WKWebView documentation. I have a feeling that I am just missing a vital piece of information that will stitch everything together.

I cannot download the html and display that way because the actual website it’s not just basic HTML and CSS

Comment: Try to create a custom renderer using a WkWebView,call like :`NSUrlRequest request = new NSUrlRequest(url, NSUrlRequestCachePolicy.ReturnCacheDataElseLoad, 60);`

Comment: How would I initialize the caching? Does WKWebkit take care of that or do I have to directly state to cache it?

Comment: Since I am still so new to appdev, custom renderers scare me. Can you offer some good references to learn, any help is appreciated. I want to understand this but it is very overwhelming getting started.

Comment: you could look at the [custom-renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/)

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed by having the web developer also set the Application Cache in addition to the Cache Storage. As of iOS 10 WKWebview default is set to cache the webview but AppCache must be set in the website level. Android can handle if just the Cache Storage is set but iOS cannot.